# Invoking Web-Service without using JAX-RS

Tags: web-services, spring

I have a Web-Service with Restfull Jax-rs and I have created WSClient with Restfull but without using Jax-rs. I am using Spring3.0, Tomcat.
Here is my WSClient:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactory;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Controller
public class WSClientController {
    @Inject
    @Named("restTemplate")
    protected RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private final static String articleServiceUrl = "http://HOST:8080/WS/Service/getAccounts.html";

    @RequestMapping(value={"/accountMasterRoot"}, method={org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET}, headers={"Accept=application/xml, application/json"})
    public List<AccountMasterWS> getAccountMasterRoot() {       
        try {           
            AccountMasterRoot ac = restTemplate.getForObject(articleServiceUrl, AccountMasterRoot.class);           
            List<AccountMasterWS> listAccounts = ac.getAccountMasterWS();

            return  listAccounts;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

but when I try to invoke Web-Service with this code I am getting error like :

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read [class com.nmmc.fas.ws.model.AccountMasterRoot]; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: accountMasterRoot : accountMasterRoot
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.readFromSource(MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java:61)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:307)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:177)
    at com.nmmc.ws.controller.WSClientController.getAccountMasterRoot(WSClientController.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: XStream unmarshalling exception; nested exception is com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: accountMasterRoot : accountMasterRoot
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.convertXStreamException(XStreamMarshaller.java:498)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:476)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalReader(XStreamMarshaller.java:459)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshalInputStream(XStreamMarshaller.java:450)
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshalStreamSource(AbstractMarshaller.java:368)
    at org.springframework.oxm.support.AbstractMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractMarshaller.java:134)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.readFromSource(MarshallingHttpMessageConverter.java:113)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: accountMasterRoot : accountMasterRoot
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:68)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DynamicProxyMapper.realClass(DynamicProxyMapper.java:71)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.PackageAliasingMapper.realClass(PackageAliasingMapper.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ClassAliasingMapper.realClass(ClassAliasingMapper.java:86)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.ArrayMapper.realClass(ArrayMapper.java:96)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.MapperWrapper.realClass(MapperWrapper.java:38)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CachingMapper.realClass(CachingMapper.java:52)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.HierarchicalStreams.readClassType(HierarchicalStreams.java:29)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:136)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:33)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:923)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:899)
    at org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller.unmarshal(XStreamMarshaller.java:473)
```

I am totally stuck here, please help me what should I do changes in my code...

Comment: It looks like you are struggling to deserialize xml into a class.  What does the xml you are getting look like?

Comment: @nicholas.hauschild Thanks for replay, here I have added my xml in answer section... Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi here I am able to find out the solution now its working when I used webClient.
My controller snipped like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/accountMasterRoot.etenderingWS" }, method = { org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET })
    public List<AccountMasterWS> getAccountMasterRoot() {

        try {

            WebClient client = WebClient.create(articleServiceUrl);
            AccountMasterRoot a = client.accept("application/xml").get(
                    AccountMasterRoot.class);
            List<AccountMasterWS> wsl = a.getAccountMasterWS();
            for (int i = 0; i < wsl.size(); i++) {
                Long code = wsl.get(i).getCode();
                String name = wsl.get(i).getName();
                System.out.println("Code    " + code + "    name    " + name);
            }
            System.out.println("End of WebService");

            return wsl;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <import resource="etendering-servlet.xml" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.nmmc.ws" />
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                             <property name="aliases"> <props> <prop key="listAccounts">com.nmmc.fas.ws.model.AccountMasterRoot</prop> 
                                 </props> 
                                </property> 
                            <property name="annotatedClasses">
                                <list>
                                    <value>com.nmmc.fas.ws.model.AccountMasterRoot</value>
                                </list>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```